# Json argument in Spark submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-submit

My spark-submit command :

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --class spark_package.import_jar s3://test-system/test.jar "{\"localparameter\" : {\"mail\": \"\", \"clusterid\": \"test\", \"clientCd\": \"1000\", \"processid\": \"1234\"} }"
```

Here i want to pass the clientCd as parameter to my Scala code.

My scala code :

```
package Spark_package

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object SampleFile {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("SampleFile").getOrCreate()
    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SampleFile")
    val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext


    val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").load("s3a://test-system/data/*.gz")

    df.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
    val res = spark.sql("select count(*) from data where client_cd = $clientCd")

    res.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("header","true").mode("Overwrite").save("s3a://dev-system/bkup/")

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

Here My question is how to pass clientCd as parameter to my code.

```
 val res = spark.sql("select count(*) from data where client_cd = $clientCd")
```

Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append all program arguments in the end of `spark-submit`, they will be available in `args` at `main`.

eg. `spark-submit --class xxx --deploy-mode xxx.jar arg1 arg2`

then you can parse your `arg1` by a json unmarshaller.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. how can we do this? I am new to this coding.